# Default select option based on current year

Tags: javascript

I need a JS that autoselect as default option the current year from this select-dropdown.
Now we are in 2022, so the defaul option must be 2022.

Thanks.

```
<select id="yearDP">
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2022">2023</option>
<option value="2022">2024</option>
<option value="2022">2025</option>
<option value="2022">2026</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Magic if you use a Documentation !](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="yearDP">
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2025">2025</option>
    <option value="2026">2026</option>
</select>

<script>
    const year = new Date().getFullYear()
    let selectBox = document.getElementById('yearDP')

    selectBox.value = year
</script>
```